# Issue Connecting to Mac Agent from Windows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got the following issue while connecting to Mac Agent.

Previously when using Xcode 9.2 i got no such issues but later when updated to Xcode 9.3 the following log was showed.

Getting this error even when the Mac credentials are correct.

```
      Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 4.8.0.760-d15-5+fc93f3f5b
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.AccountManager|Information|0|VS2017 Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Not logged in, using iOS Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Not logged in, using Android Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.Inspector|Information|0|Inspector extension loaded
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|Solution loaded: 'App1'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|running fixup on project 'F:\Bharath\Project Materials\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|running fixup on project 'F:\Bharath\Project Materials\App1\App1\App1.iOS\App1.iOS.csproj'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ContinuousPlayerDeviceProvider|Information|0|Start()
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from DisconnectedState to ConfiguringState on 192.168.XXX.XX (192.168.XXX.XX)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Checking host configuration for connecting to '192.168.XXX.XX'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|Failed to execute 'grep "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJ0uNVUuKpZY5t3ea5q5JjTFn7AGfrSHeyDGJ0S83Plh05t4neDyk8jtt7WSqFM8FeY31i5N55FaYOnxwRvzcYJxo01PWuudNKtB6L4pk0PxN1cYTG8RqCLw0DM9GVL4cULgENsofpkxCu648qpIbbXl+Bwj7ScP8JV8b9vMFART59iWYlF1iuzFoLt4NE3uX24m7R/W2G9ypxDRHRB5YAAeVXPm9j5BlHzLHaCmIQezJr7T/d0PEr/09IV1CrQ56Q11RPMH7YHXILzHKhmYO+gwEUrgwvYo68/9P7E3nbzCVEikOHIdxAYHjd59Ma7y/u2iicEjfzwXXoMbkhuyZB GD@GD-MacBook-Pro.local" /Users/GD/.ssh/authorized_keys': ExitStatus = 1
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Checking host configuration for connecting to '192.168.XXX.XX'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from ConfiguringState to ConfiguredState on 192.168.XXX.XX (192.168.XXX.XX)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Host '192.168.XXX.XX' is configured correctly
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from ConfiguredState to ConnectingState on 192.168.XXX.XX (192.168.XXX.XX)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting connection to '192.168.XXX.XX'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Starting connection to 192.168.XXX.XX...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting connection to '192.168.XXX.XX'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Error|0|Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.Exceptions.MessagingAuthenticationException: Could not authenticate the user 'GD'R with SSH keys. Please check that both $HOME folder and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys have the appropiate permissions to use SSH. More details: Permission denied (publickey). ---> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey).
   at Renci.SshNet.ClientAuthentication.Authenticate(IConnectionInfoInternal connectionInfo, ISession session)
   at Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo.Authenticate(ISession session, IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshMessagingConnection.ConnectSsh(Boolean forwardTcpPort) in C:\d\lanes\5409\fc93f3f5\source\xamarinvs\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshMessagingConnection.cs:line 138
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__66.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\5409\fc93f3f5\source\xamarinvs\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingService.cs:line 225
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshMessagingConnection|Error|0|An unexpected error occurred with the current SSH Session
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: An established connection was aborted by the server.
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketRead(Int32 length, Byte[] buffer)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.ReceiveMessage()
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.MessageListener()
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin are you using?

Comment: Have you check that all users can access your mac?

Comment: Xamarin 4.8.0.760
Visual studio 15.5.7 Community 2017 @SushiHangover

Comment: Yes i checked it...previously i was using 9.2 after update 9.3 i got this issue @SrustiThakkar

Comment: Xcode 9 was not supported till the Visual Studio `15.6.5` release

Comment: I tried with another machine which has Visual Studio 15.6.7 in that also I am facing this issue.@SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

You always have to open XCode after you have updated it. It the most case it will install additional components and sometimes you have to accept new terms.